# Void functions can't return void functions?

Tags: php

I wonder why this is not valid:

```
Class Foobar
{
    private function foo(): void {
        return;
    }

    public function bar(): void {
        return $this->foo(); // Compile Error: A void function must not return a value
    }

}
```

I know the RFC says this:

> A function with a void return type, or void function, may either return implicitly, or have a return statement without a value

But IMHO `foo` is void, thus it should be allowed...

Comment: void function can't return _nothing_. Not even null.

Comment: `return;` actually returns `null`, not `void`

Comment: $this->foo() does not return void, but null, so you are actually returning null

Comment: what shouuld be the benefit? you can do `$this->foo(); return;`

Comment: wouldnt it be that the the foo() has no type at all so it technically returnable in this instance

Comment: I think the type checker only goes as far as identifying that you are returning *something* from a `void` function, it doesn't go as far as checking that this value will also be `void`. And indeed, why *are* you returning the return value of a `void` function from a `void` function?! Even if that *should* work out in the type system, it makes little sense. At the very least this check is identifying a code smell.

Comment: Doctrine generates `Doctrine\Proxy`es with `return parent::method()` call. It's only option to not use `void` typehint.

Answer (score 4):

`$this->foo()` does not return `void`, but `null`. So in your bar function, you are actually explicitly returning `null`, which is not allowed.